# How can I get values of checkboxes from all the fragments of a view pager, by clicking button in the main activity?

Tags: android

I am developing one android application and it has a tab layout with ViewPager setup. i have totally 8 fragments in the view pager. Each Fragment holding an RecyclerView. The recycler view row has one text and one checkbox.

Whenever the activity started it loads 8 fragments with recyclerview data. I have a button in the MainActivity, whenever the button is clicked i need to collect the checked rows from all 8 fragments and i have to send the same to the server.

i dont have any clue about the data retrieval but my UI design has been completed.

Comment: Post some of your code where you prepare your 8 fragments and set them to `ViewPager.`

Comment: I have followed the below example and inside the fragment I have added a Recycler view. https://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking in to example you followed, you can do something like:

**1. Create global objects of fragments:**

```
private OneFragment oneFragment;
private TwoFragment twoFragment;
private ThreeFragment threeFragment;
```

**2. Initialize them in `onCreate`:**

```
oneFragment = new OneFragment();
twoFragment = new TwoFragment();
threeFragment = new ThreeFragment();
```

**3. Update `setupViewPager` method:**

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(oneFragment, "ONE");
    adapter.addFragment(new twoFragment, "TWO");
    adapter.addFragment(new threeFragment, "THREE");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

**4. Create `getSelectedValues` mehthod in all fragments:**

- Create `getSelectedValues` in all fragments which will return
  selected items.

**5. Get selected values from `onClick` method in `MainActivity`:**

```
    if (oneFragment != null) {
        oneFragment.getSelectedValues(); // here you'll get selected values of oneFragment
    }

    if (twoFragment != null) {
        twoFragment.getSelectedValues(); // here you'll get selected values of twoFragment
    }

    if (threeFragment != null) {
        threeFragment.getSelectedValues(); // here you'll get selected values of threeFragment
    }
```

Comment: @Jegan I'am glad my solution worked for you. You can **upvote** answer also. :-)